# Very long time for Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start

Tags: session, redis, memcached, ee-1.14, ee-1.14.1.0

We are using Magento EE 1.14.1.0 and are seeing very long times for  `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start` method. We tried using Memcached and Redis for session storage both with the same result.

Is this normal? Is this a New Relic problem? Any ideas how to fix it?

Screenshots below:
[image: Memcached session]
[image: Redis session]

I will be very grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: if you use DB for session - does it take long?

Answer (score 2):

There is multiple issues for this case.

First Magento recommend Memcache for M2, I suppose the same for M1 : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/memcache/memcache.html
We had experiment this issue with Redis and we change `session_save` to `db`.

The second, is located here : `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Session::gc`. Randomly Magento clean session. This clean cause a lock. A solution is to disable this random clean and use a cron to do the job (overload this class and change `$_automaticCleaningFactor` value to 0). This works great for us (with db).

Hope this help,